# how can I import ALL classes in a python py file to another class in another py file?

Tags: python, class, import, namespaces

### Files tree:

```
\
├── main.py
├── classes.py
```

### classes.py

- i defined 3 classes in this file

---

```
class clsA: 
    name = "clsA"
class clsB: 
    name = "clsB"
class clsC: 
    name = "clsC"
```

### main.py

- my purpose is to import all classes in `classes.py` into class `main.classlist`，but i don't want to explicitly enumerate all those classes name in code.

---

```
class classlist:

    # from classes import clsA, clsB, clsC
    ## ^ above line able to work, but need to explicitly list all those classes name

    from classes import *
    ## ^ above line not working : SyntaxError: import * only allowed at module level


print(classlist.clsA.name)
# expected print out "clsA"
```

so is there simple way i can import all classes in `classes.py` in `main.classlist` without explicitly list them?

or is there an easy way i can list all classes name in `classes.py` into a `[list]` then try to import that list in `main.classlist`?

BTW, python 3.8+

thanks.

Comment: Just move out `from classes import *` and put it with other imports statements, then initialize the classes inside the `ClassList`,

Answer (score -1):

you need to create an `__init__.py` file in the same directory and add the following code into it:

> ****init**.py**

```
__all__ = ['classes']
```

In `main.py` you just have to import classes.

> **main.py**

```
import classes


class classlist:
    pass


print(classes.clsA.name)
print (classes.clsB)
```

Note: In python class names are written in `CamelCase convention` like `ClassList`.